# Systemd service not running with read FIFO

Tags: bash, systemd, services, fifo, ipc

I wrote a script that listens for commands from a FIFO and collects couple of files for debugging on my raspberry pi, all ***working fine*** until i decided to write a systemd unit file for it. running `systemctl start crashcollector` will start the script but it never reads anything from the pipe it's running but not doing anything, `systemctl stop crashcollector` takes forever to stop the service so i'm guessing something wrong with my unit file even though i wrote many that work just fine.

bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

collectCrashReport() {
    # teleport to cache dir
    cd /mnt/cache
    # remove any previous report
    rm -rf crash/crashreport_*
    # create report directory
    directory=crashreport_`cat /etc/hostname`_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
    mkdir $directory
    cd $directory
    # snatch all the logs
    cp -r /var/log/ .
    ps --no-headers -ax > processes.dump
    # dump dmesg to file 
    dmesg > dmesg.dump
    # create crash dir
    mkdir crash
    # zip the whole thing
    zip -qr /mnt/cache/crash/"$directory.zip" .
    # remove collection dir
    rm -rf /mnt/cache/crashreport_*
    # done and done
}

# check if already running and kill
PIDFILE=/var/run/crashcollector.pid
# check if already running
if [ -f $PIDFILE ]; then
    kill `cat $PIDFILE`
fi
echo $$ > $PIDFILE

cleanup() {
    rm -f $PIDFILE
    exit 0
}
# trap them signals 
trap "cleanup" INT TERM EXIT

that_awesome_pipe="CCPipe"
[ -p $that_awesome_pipe ] || mkfifo $that_awesome_pipe
chmod 766 $that_awesome_pipe
while :; do
    if read line; then
        case $line in
        "collect")
            collectCrashReport
            ;;
        *)
            log "Received bad command $line, ignoring..."
            ;;
        esac    
    fi
done <"$that_awesome_pipe"
```

Systemd unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Crash report collector
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/crashCollector
ExecStop=/usr/bin/kill -9 `cat /var/run/crashcollector.pid`
KillMode=process
Restart=always
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

not sure what exactly i'm missing here removing that `if read line` block makes everything work just fine.

Comment: Try replacing commands enclosed in back ticks (`) with $() as backticks are rather dated now.

Comment: Also, you could perhaps try "while read line do" as opposed to using if.

Comment: changing the `if read` to `while read` didn't solve it

Comment: ^ No... remove the `if read...fi` construct entirely (but keep its contents), and change the `while :; do` to `while read line; do`.

Comment: You really also ought to quote your variables when they're used. For example `case $line in` should be `case "$line" in`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was fixed after I moved the fifo to `/tmp`; not sure what that changes, but things work smoothly now.

Answer (score 3):

There are so many things wrong, there.

- Do not treat `ExecStart` and `ExecStop` as if they are shell command lines.  They are not.  The systemd manual does warn against this.  Shell expansions such as command substitution are *not* available in these service unit file settings.  It is *not* the shell language.
- Do not create a PID file mechanism when the place that you are starting from is having an actual service manager to hand.  PID files are a mechanism that we have known to be broken since the 1980s, and that proper service management completely does away with the need for.  You have a service manager.  *It* will ensure that at most only one instance of the service runs at any time.  *It* will track the process ID.  *It* will deal with sending termination signals to the service process when the service is shut down.
- Do not put basic server-side stuff into the server process, such as creating the FIFO and opening its server end.

Do things this way:

- Create a socket unit to go alongside the service unit.
- Take all of the explicit handling of the FIFO out of `crashCollector`.
- Use `ListenFIFO` in the socket unit.  This will of course need an absolute pathname.
- Use `StandardInput=socket` in the service unit.
- Make your `crashcollector` script just read from its standard input.
- Take all of the PID file mucking about out of `crashCollector`.
- Take all of the signal trapping and `cleanup()` stuff out of `crashCollector`.
- Take all of the explicit killing with `ExecStop`, and the consequent bodge that you tried to do with `KillMode`, out of the service unit.
- Use `StandardError=journal` in the service unit.
- Replace `log` with a simple `echo 1>&2` to standard error.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2001).  [*Mistakes to avoid when designing Unix dæmon programs*](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/unix-daemon-design-mistakes-to-avoid.html).   Frequently Given Answers.
- Lennart Poettering et al.. *[systemd.socket](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html)*.  systemd manual pages.  Freedesktop.org.
- [How make service reading from FIFO socket](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332077/)